# List users in CouchDB with member privileges?

Tags: couchdb

In CouchDB, views on the `_users` database are restricted to admins with the following message:

```
{
    "error":"forbidden",
    "reason":"Only administrators can view design docs in the users database."
}
```

What would be the best way for a non-admin user to get a list of users?

#### Attempted solutions

- I tried adding a user as a member of `_users` but the same message above appears.
- It doesn't look like I can set permissions on specific views [according to the documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/ddoc/common.html) (however there is an `options` entry I can't find any documentation on).
- The above 'forbidden' message isn't in `_users/_design/_auth` `validate_doc_update` function so it doesn't seem I can edit `validate_doc_update` to allow users to view this database.

To give context: I'm creating an application which needs to be aware of all other users with a specific role so that they can interact with each other.

Comment: If it is possible to do what you're attempting, it is a serious security flaw that needs to be fixed immediately.

Comment: @Flimzy Why is it a security flaw for one authenticated user with a given role such as 'client' to list only the names of all other users with role 'client'?

Comment: Because it makes no sense that just because I can log into my bank's web site, and I have a role of "savings account holder", that I should be able to see the names of all other savings account holders.

Comment: The level of access you're talking about needs to be application-specific. It should not be built into the database.

Comment: @Flimzy It may not work in the context of a bank, but there are many examples where this functionality is desired, such as forum directory, multiplayer games, and social media. This includes my target application.

Comment: Sure, there are applications where it may make sense. That's why it should be application logic. Although I'm sure Mark Zuckerberg would be the first to tell you that social media is _not_ one such application.

Comment: @Flimzy That doesn't explain why what I'm asking would be a security flaw...

Comment: CouchDB, unlike say MySQL, is meant to be publicly-accessible. This means that it must live up to much higher default security standards. Access to user lists is, by default, an insecure thing to give to _anyone_.

Comment: @Flimzy "higher default security standards" and whether something is publicly accessible or not isn't a valid reason to call this kind of functionality a security flaw. As I already mentioned, this would be created by the admin, and served to authenticated users with a specific role (but not an admin role). Alternatively I could give all these special users 'admin' privileges but this would be an actual security flaw. Also, if you didn't know, public data can be stored in the `_users` database via `public_fields`: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/intro/security.html#users-public-information

Comment: You're essentially saying you want your database to have built-in application logic. CouchDB does blur the lines between the database and the app in many ways, but I still don't see that as a very useful feature request. But feel free to prove me wrong, and submit a pull request to the CouchDB project, or fork or write your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no possibility to access the _users database without admin privileges. But you might consider writing an server side API to look up your user list. Then access your data via an AJAX call. If you already have an API, that should not be much of an problem. Otherwise you might want to take a look at Express: https://expressjs.com/

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this solution. Getting a whole API layer for this was overkill. Instead I made the application register the user in a separate database upon login. Then, other users are able to pull a view of this separate database, thus getting the list of the users of interest.